# How do I set the window minimize and maximize speed without using the shift-key

Tags: macos, mac, animation

I would like to setup my computer (Macbook running snow leopard) so that it will maximize and minimize the windows slowly. I know that this can be done by holding on the shift key while minimizing but can I set it as default so that I don't have to hold the shift key down?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You'll probably get tired of the animation pretty soon...

Comment: I'm curious to know why you'd want this, too.

Comment: Reducing information anxiety. When computer do things faster than I can think, it can get out of control. This helps to slow it down a little. For what I do in creatives, efficiency isn't always a top criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by using the Applescript below. You'll need [CornerClick](http://greg.vario.us/cornerclick/) and you can find more info on [MacWorld](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20091122005247214).

```
tell application "System Events"
  keystroke "m" using command down
  key down shift
  delay 0.3
  key up shift
end tell

tell application "System Events"
  set proc to name of the first process whose frontmost is true
  tell process proc
    -- add error trapping here
    tell its window 1
      set w to its name
      if get value of attribute "AXMinimized" is false then
        tell application "System Events"
          keystroke "m" using command down
          key down shift
          delay 0.3
          key up shift
        end tell
      end if
    end tell
    --
  end tell
end tell

say "Collapse" using "Alex"
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without cornerclick, that is if you click on minimize it will evoke the slow animation effect?

Comment: If you want the slow effect, you can hit the shift button while minimizing the window

Comment: Michiel, yes. But I want to know if I can set it as default so I don't have to use the shift key. Is that possible as an applescript or setting some defaults through terminal?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But why would you nee such an time- and RAM absorbing process?

Comment: I find all those zipping windows actually increases my informational anxiety :-)

Answer (score 0):

### [Moom](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/moom/id419330170?mt=12)

> Moom allows you to easily move and zoom windows—on one display, or to another display—using either the mouse or the keyboard.

[image: Moom Screenshot]

Comment: Moom looks very interesting. A bit like the Aerosnap on Window 7. Although I am still looking for slower transitions despite Mountain Lion has made a lot of moving around much smoother in process. I thought there would be some animation speed variable that I could just change.